# Recovering data from a plot

Tags: plotting, data

Suppose I have an image which I got from a screenshot \
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Iuj2.png  \

Nothing else is there.

Now I want my x-axis range (0,1) and also y axis range (0,1). Is it possible to assign this range and then recovering data from the graph?

Comment: If none of the solutions in the linked thread work for you, please edit your post to explain why they did not work.